# Create array with dynamic name

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm currently trying to make a loop that creates arrays, but I need to set the name of the array dynamic, so that all arrays have a name like $array0, $array1.

I am fetching rows from a MySQL table that all have an ID, that ID is stored in $rowData[0], so I want make arrays that have a name with this ID.

I currently have this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0) {
while($rowData = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<pre>';-
    $array . $rowData[0] = new ArrayObject($rowData);
    print_r($array . $rowData[0]);
    echo "<h1>" . $array . $rowData[0] . [1] . "<h1>";
    echo '</pre>';
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just an FYI: `mysql_` functions are deprecated and have been removed in PHP 7. Use `mysqli_`or `PDO` functions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That negates the value of using arrays, just do:

```
$array[$rowData[0]] = new ArrayObject($rowData);
```

Then you access `$array[1]` etc...

What you are attempting is variable variables, but rarely if ever are they better than using an array. If `$rowData[0]` is 1 then this would create `$array1`:

```
${'array' . $rowData[0]} = new ArrayObject($rowData);
```

NOTE for mysql_*() functions:

> **This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
>   7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used**. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - mysqli_query()
> - PDO::query()